# Origin of the terms "safety" and "liveness" for concurrent algorithm properties?

Tags: terminology, reference-request, concurrency

Properties of concurrent algorithms are usually divided into two categories:

1. **Safety** - something *must not* happen.

   Properties in this category are for example partial correctness and sometimes deadlock-freedom (the latter depending on the author).
2. **Liveness** - something that *must* happen *eventually*.

   Properties in this category are for example termination and starvation-freedom.

Which publication introduced these terms?

---

The oldest reference I was able to find is ["Proving the Correctness of Multiprocess Programs" by Leslie Lamport](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/proving.pdf), dated March 1977:

> To prove the correctness of a program, one must prove two essentially different types of properties about it, which we call *safety* and *liveness* properties. [...]

It does, however, not claim to introduce these terms.

Comment: I don't know who introduced these terms into concurrent algorithms, but they were already used with similar meanings [in Petri nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net#Liveness) [before 1977](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=cdr:1,cd_max:1977&tbm=bks&q=liveness+petri&gws_rd=cr&ei=xbPxVeeoG8fsaLv6jugD).

Comment: @Gilles [Lamport has commented that](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/pubs.html#proving) "This paper (of 1977) introduced the concepts of safety and liveness as the proper generalizations of partial correctness and termination to concurrent programs.  It also introduced the terms "safety" and "liveness" for those classes of properties.  I stole those terms from Petri nets, where they have similar but formally very different meanings.  (Safety of a Petri net is a particular safety property; liveness of a Petri net is not a liveness property.) "

Comment: @hengxin That's a claim that he introduced the terms! Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lamport commented on his paper "Proving the Correctness of Multiprocess Programs"](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/pubs.html#proving) as follows:

> This paper introduced the concepts of safety and liveness as the proper generalizations of partial correctness and termination to concurrent programs. It also introduced the terms "safety" and "liveness" for those classes of properties. I stole those terms from Petri nets, where they have similar but formally very different meanings. (Safety of a Petri net is a particular safety property; liveness of a Petri net is not a liveness property.)

This can be seen as a claim that he (Lamport) has introduced the terms.